# Matrix-based CVXPY quadratic program not DCP

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

cvxpy supports matrix-based expressions, but seems to not recognise them as quadratic programs.

Here's a super-simple example:

```py
import cvxpy
Pi = cvxpy.Variable((10, 5))

objective = cvxpy.Minimize( cvxpy.trace(Pi.T @ Pi) )
problem = cvxpy.Problem(objective)
problem.solve()
```

`Trace(Pi.T @ Pi)` is just the sum of squares of entries of `Pi` (so convex/quadratic etc.), yet I get this exception:

```py
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
var25.T @ var25
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this how it is?

This is a super-simple example, I'm trying to solve something more complex, but perhaps this is the simplest place to start. I'm using cvxpy version 1.1.1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cvxpy has a DCP ruleset to be able to prove things *by construction*. As the general problem of deciding convexity is NP-hard, there are of course limitations on what (or how efficient) this *language* can express.

Sometimes you just need to provide more structure.

Rule number 1:

- Loot at the [available functions](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html#) and pick the most structured one!

In your case:

- `norm(X, “nuc”)`

  - the root should probably be irrelevant in your case

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know it's a NP-hard problem btw. Do you mind me asking, do expressions like this have nice representations too? `tr(A @ PI @ B @ Pi.T)` or `diag(Pi @ C @ Pi.T) @ const_vector` ? Without resorting to to `cvxpy.vec(Pi)`, which I guess is the nuclear option...

Comment: I don't know. Anything is possible: from you cannot express it at all (e.g. not convex) to: there might be something elegant. This depends on what those parameters refer to obviously. (the latter just looks like diag(quad_form())